# Sorted arrays doesn't delete what I want

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, tableview, sorting

I have a sorted NSMutableArray which works perfectly and all though when I try to delete an object it crashes the app then when I reload the app it didn't delete the right one.

I known that is due to the fact that this is now a sorted array because before I implemented this feature it worked fine though I haven't got a clue of how to fix it.

Here is the code I use to delete things from the array:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tv commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ( editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete ) {
        Patient *thisPatient = [patients objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [patients removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if (patients.count == 0) {
            [super setEditing:NO animated:YES];
            [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
        }
        [self deletePatientFromDatabase:thisPatient.patientid];
        [tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    }
}
```

It is being stopped at this line:

```
[tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
```

Here is the code that I use for sorting the array:

```
-(void) processForTableView:(NSMutableArray *)items {

    for (Patient *thisPatient in items) {
        NSString *firstCharacter = [thisPatient.patientName substringToIndex:1];
        if (![charIndex containsObject:firstCharacter]) {
            [charIndex addObject:firstCharacter];
            [charCount setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:firstCharacter];
        } else {
            [charCount setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[charCount objectForKey:firstCharacter] intValue] + 1] forKey:firstCharacter];
        }
    }
    charIndex = (NSMutableArray *) [charIndex sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
        NSString *letter = [charIndex objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
        NSPredicate *search = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"patientName beginswith[cd] %@", letter];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"patientName" ascending:YES];

    NSArray *filteredArray = [[patients filteredArrayUsingPredicate:search] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
    if ( nil == cell ) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    NSLog(@"indexPath.row = %d, patients.count = %d", indexPath.row, patients.count);
    Patient *thisPatient = [filteredArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", thisPatient.patientName, thisPatient.patientSurname];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    if (self.editing) {
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

I suspect this is quite a common thing that happens when you sort an array though it may not be.

Please say if you want any more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not neccessarily because your array is sorted, but because the array you are populating your table from is not the same as the array that you are removing the object from.

Where are you sorting the `patients` array? Is the actual `patients` array being sorted or are you sorting it in your tableView delegates method and not actually sorting `patients`?

The reason for this is that the index of the object you deleted is not the same as the index that it has in the actual `patients` array (because one is sorted and one is not). Because of this, it is first deleting the wrong object, then it crashes because the tableView expects one to be deleted (so that it can animate that cell being removed) but the wrong one was deleted.

Comment: Could you post your tableView delegate methods? And the code where you are sorting it?

Comment: Should I unsort it then sort it again

Comment: What you should do is in the method where you create the charIndex, actually sort the `patients` array, and then just use the new `patients` array as the data for the tableView.

Comment: So recreate the array effectivly though a sorted version?

Comment: Ya, basically sort the array once rather than sorting it everytime in the tableView's delegate method using that charIndex.

Comment: So in the viewDidAppear function

Comment: Or just at the end of your `processForTableView` function.

Comment: When I try that though it crashes when it reaches this line: `NSString *letter = [charIndex objectAtIndex:[index section]];`

Comment: I already told you what's wrong. You need to actually sort your array so that the data in the table is in the same order as it is in your array.

Comment: But I can't as I use the section variable of tableView which you can't just set where you want

Comment: It looks like you are making your data sorted alphabetically with the first letter separating sections. What you could do is similar to the way you are getting the `filteredArray`, you could do that as a loop in your sort method for each letter and create an array for each of them and add each array to the `patients` array, then you can do `NSArray *currentLetter = [patients objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]` and then `Patient *thisPatient = [currentLetter objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`.

Comment: Didn't  work it gives this error `-[Patient objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75ced30`

Comment: Make sure you don't actually add all of the other arrays to the `patients` array, but you instead create a separate NSMutableArray (ex `tempArray`) and then after looping through all of them do (`self.patients = tempArray`). That way the patients array will get rid of the objects it had before. Remember also that you will also have to change how you add objects to the array and remove them, but that should be simple and easy.